# How can i get more information about errors on aws lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a simple CRUD application with Aws: Lambda, ApiGateway, S3. When i run my lambda 90% of the executions are working as expected, but a 10% returns the following error:

[image]

Even with that, the function does his behavior successfully (bddRepo.save(), ...) except it cant return the 200 OK {"response":"response"}

How can I identify where this error is triggering?

Comment: You should be checking the CloudWatch logs for the function to determine what the issue is. Is the function simply taking too long to respond?